# WebClient.DownloadString(url) Errors with FormatException

Tags: .net, webclient, downloadstring

I don't understand why this line of code is throwing this error.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

[image: DateTime Format Exception?]

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Double.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at micro.Updater.start(Object obj) in C:\Users\Windows\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Micro\Updater.cs:line 22
   at System.Threading._TimerCallback.TimerCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback(Object state)
```

Comment: Please click the "Copy exception detail to the clipboard" from that dialog then put the text it copied in to your question as a edit inside a code block

Comment: Can you also include the full code of the `start` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PDB file is likely out of sync with your code. From your stack trace you can see the error is happening inside of the `System.Double.Parse` you call from your `start` method. It thinks that you call `Double.Parse` on line 22 but line 22 is your web client call.

Try doing a clean then rebuild. Also check that your program is in Debug mode instead of Release mode, that can cause it too. If that does not fix it you will need to look at the code by hand to find that `Double.Parse` call.